# Удалить совпадающие элементы списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Само задание:

> В заданном неупорядоченном списке оставить по одному в каждой группе
> совпадающих элементов, сохранив порядок следования остальных

Вот я пробовал это сделать, но это не совсем то, т.к после преобразования из списка в множество информация о порядке элементов удаляется, а мне же надо что бы порядок остался таким же по условию задания

```
def spisok():
  spisok1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 3]
  y = set(spisok1)
  for i in y:
    print(i,end = ' ')
spisok()
```

Comment: А какая у вас версия питона? По-моему, с 3.6 или 3.7 множество (и словари) сохраняют порядок элементов. Вообще, они работают через хеширование, из-за этого ранее порядок не сохранялся

Comment: @gil9red, у меня 3.8+, порядок не сохраняется, да и не должен в общем то по логике

Comment: @Zhihar, мб это касалось только ключей словарей. Добавил ответ через ключи словаря :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а вы проверьте на таком `spisok1 = [7, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3]`
и совсем другой результат

можно сделать так:

```
spisok1 = [7, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3]

trash = set()
arr = []

for i in spisok1:
  if i not in trash:
    arr.append(i)
    trash.add(i)

print(arr)
```

подольше работать будет этот код (из-за более долгого поиска):

```
arr = []

for i in spisok1:
  if i not in arr:
    arr.append(i)
```

можно сделать в 1 строчку, но код будет дикий:

```
arr = [spisok1[0]] + [spisok1[pos] for pos in range(1, len(spisok1)) if spisok1[pos:].count(spisok1[pos]) == spisok1.count(spisok1[pos])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Для питона 3.7 (для CPython это версия 3.6) и выше можно работать через ключи словаря, т.к. порядок добавления ключей в словари сохраняется.

Пример:

```
spisok1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 3]
spisok1 = list(dict.fromkeys(spisok1))
print(spisok1)
```